# How to test a component with updates background depend on state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that changes the background image depending on the state. I added simplified codes down below.

Since I fetch an image from the server on state changes, the background image was flashing. This is the reason I load them to DOM with `preloadImage()` function. This function solved the issue.

The problem starts with testing. See the testing file!

```
const BackgroundImage = styled`
  ...
  background-image: ${(props) => props.bg && `url(${props.bg})`};
`

const preloadImage = (src, wrapperRef, callback) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  img.style.display = 'none';
  img.dataset.testid = 'preloaded-image';

  const el = wrapperRef.current;
  el.innerHTML = '';
  el.appendChild(img);

  img.onload = () => typeof callback === 'function' && callback(src);
};    

const Panel = (defaultBG) => {
  const imageCacheRef = useRef();
  const [bg, setBG] = useState(defaultBG);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImage = async () => {
      const imageSrc = await import(`https://fakeimageapi.com/${bg}.png`);
      return preloadImage(imageSrc.default, imageCacheRef, setImage);
    }

    try {
      await fetchImage()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div ref={imageCacheRef}>
      <BackgroundImage bg={bg} data-testid="bg" />

      <button onClick={ () => setBG('cat') }>Cat</button>
      <button onClick={ () => setBG('dog') }>Cat</button>
      <button onClick={ () => setBG('rabbit') }>Cat</button>
      <button onClick={ () => setBG('parrot') }>Cat</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the test suite written with Testing Library.

```
import { render, waitFor, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Panel', () => {
  test('Sets background-image correctly', async () => {
    render(<Panel defaultBG="panda" />)
    expect(screen.getByTestId('bg')).toHaveStyle(
      'background-image: url(panda.png);',
    );
  })
})
```

Unfortunately, this test fails. The problem (I guess) that I use a callback after the image is loaded inside `useEffect`. How can I final this test with a successful result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I added a test-id to the image inside preloadImage() and loaded the image with the fireEvent method. That's it!

```
import { render, waitFor, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Panel', () => {
  test('Sets background-image correctly', async () => {
    render(<Panel defaultBG="panda" />)

    const image = await waitFor(() => screen.getByTestId('preloaded-image'));
    fireEvent.load(image);

    expect(screen.getByTestId('bg')).toHaveStyle(
      'background-image: url(panda.png);',
    );
  })
})
```

Also, some refactoring on `preloadImage()` function.

```
const preloadImage = (src, wrapperRef, callback) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  img.style.display = 'none';
  img.dataset.testid = 'preloaded-image';

  const el = wrapperRef.current;
  el.innerHTML = '';
  el.appendChild(img);

  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    img.onload = () => callback(src);
  }
};
```